# Can't play a game/DLC after a license transfer

Tags: ubisoft-connect

So, I made a license transfer with my friend. I signed into his profile to download a DLC or game. Then, when it finished downloading, I signed out of his profile and went back onto mine. Then I tried to play the game/DLC, however the game refuses to launch, and the DLC for it is also unavailable. The only way I can play them is if I'm on his profile. Why can't I play them on my account?

I also made a transfer with another friend and tried to download the games/DLC, but I can't play them on my account. Why not?

Comment: Far Cry 4 uses uPlay, correct?  I'd start with their support first.

Comment: You are aware license transfer means you are giving the game? As in.. you don't have it anymore, you can't play it. It is now theirs, not yours.

Comment: are you even able to transfer a license? A quick google search found the only means of transfering a game is through contacting Ubisoft directly, with a realllllly good reason

Comment: If you attempted to get the game working between two people, you should have just bought two copies..

Answer (score 5):

License transfer means you gave the game to someone else. It is now their game so your account is no longer authorized to play it.